# How can I print R output into Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I see everybody on this website posting their R outputs from the R console into the question boxes into a nice neat format. How can I do the same?

Basically I want to show in a question box exactly what I see in my R studio console. Copy paste does not work because the rows link together.

Comment: Also note that a copy/paste of the results of `dput(object)` will let someone paste your object into their R console, which is very useful for sharing a test object. (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)

Comment: And after `dput`, the very useful CTRL-K to format what you pasted into the  Stack* page.

Answer (score 6):

Try the FAQ and study the formatting bar on top of the box. The two curly braces are formatted code and four indents do the same.

Comment: Also (though perhaps not directly an answer to the question) if you need to have code within some text, you can enclose it in backquotes (\` \`) giving code formatting : `carfit <- lm(dist~speed, data = cars)` - which is sometimes convenient.